# how do i delete records older than 90 days from a table in postgres

Tags: postgresql, sql-delete

Please I have a very large table that store historical data and I want a query that can help me to delete rows/records that are older than 90 days on that table

Comment: Is there any timestamp in a row?

Comment: Hi yes the table has a column that has a timestamp

Answer (score 2):

```
delete from table_name
where timestamp_column < now() - interval '90 days'
```

Answer (score -1):

enclose the `(now() - interval '90 days'))`

select `(now() - interval '90 days'))`

bodmas can apply here. hence without enclosing you may get wrong result, use below

`delete from table_name where timestamp_column < (now() - interval '90 days'))`

Comment: What's the last parenthesis closing?

Comment: @fanbondi I don't understand your question sir!